# z3py: How to check trace information when using z3 python api

Tags: logic, constraints, z3, smt, z3py

Suppose I want to check the trace information of "random_split". I wrote

```
enable_trace("random_split")
```

in my python script that is using z3 python api, but nothing shows up.

I wonder how should I check trace information when using z3py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traces are only available in debug mode, so you need to compile Z3 yourself with `python scripts/mk_make.py --debug`. If the trace doesn't produce any output, then that particular piece of code is never reached, so it never gets to print anything.

Comment: When I recompiled Z3 with "--debug", I saw error like "z3-z3-4.4.1/build/../src/util/mpz.h:347: undefined reference to `tout'". This ticket talked about the same error: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/243                                Any idea how should I fix this problem? (I am using version 4.4.1)

Comment: See the discussion on github. Before going any further, make sure you have the latest version of the sources.